# how to get HTML/JSON from Instagram URL as a Browser in php?

Tags: php, url, browser, file-get-contents, instagram-api

As you know instagram Suspended his API,but for my app, i use below codes to get JSON of instagram page's posts:

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
$urlvars = urlencode('{"id":"'.$user_id.'","first":12,"after":"'.$end_cursor.'"}');
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash={$__query_hash}&variables={$urlvars}"; 
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        "http" => array(
            "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"
        )
    )
);  
$json = file_get_contents($url,false, $context);
```

but it shows below error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=42323d64886122307be10013ad2dcc44&amp;variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%22589638973%22%2C%22first%22%3A12%2C%22after%22%3A%22AQCjxNvHU5N8KvembUhB58LBSGbZJ2q-D5aPZox2O8Mk2W5y_1eKUvvNnloRTjqyyrYNNyr1kDtpJWTZqFb_U5sUMKvFtS_bPzqVtiqh3Y7V4A%22%7D): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in C:\wamp\www\smprogram\instagram_api\get_page\index.php on line 49
```

also when i open `https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=42323d64886122307be10013ad2dcc44&amp;variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%22589638973%22%2C%22first%22%3A12%2C%22after%22%3A%22AQCjxNvHU5N8KvembUhB58LBSGbZJ2q-D5aPZox2O8Mk2W5y_1eKUvvNnloRTjqyyrYNNyr1kDtpJWTZqFb_U5sUMKvFtS_bPzqVtiqh3Y7V4A%22%7D` url by my browser, it works fine.
how can i fix it on php ?!

Comment: when I open the URL inside chrome I get a 403 Bad req. Are you maybe logged in on instagram inside your browser? I would guess so, thats probably why you receive data from the URL. I think your URL has to be changed to something using their API. You'll probably need an access token etc. (I'm just guessing tho)

Comment: @b101 , yes , you right . I logged in.

Comment: then you can probably only see the content inside your browser, because you are logged in. To fix your problem you will have to change the URL and query the Instagram API the way it is meant to be and described in the documentary. You will need an access token and what not. Take a look at the docu, it should be pretty straightforward